# Merging UNION ALL rows to remove NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT journey.id, TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed))), '%H:%i') AS departure, null AS arrival
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
INNER JOIN link l1 ON l1.section = pattern.section AND l1.stop = "370023139"
INNER JOIN link l2 ON l2.section = pattern.section AND l2.id <= l1.id
WHERE journey.service = "11-252-_-y08-1" AND journey_day.day = 1 AND journey.code NOT IN (SELECT journey
                                                                                          FROM journey_non_operation
                                                                                          WHERE "2015-03-01" BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) AND pattern.direction = "outbound"
GROUP BY journey.id

UNION ALL

SELECT journey.id, null AS departure, TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed))), '%H:%i') AS arrival
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
INNER JOIN link l1 ON l1.section = pattern.section AND l1.stop = "1000DEHS7812"
INNER JOIN link l2 ON l2.section = pattern.section AND l2.id <= l1.id
WHERE journey.service = "11-252-_-y08-1" AND journey_day.day = 1 AND journey.code NOT IN (SELECT journey
                                                                                          FROM journey_non_operation
                                                                                          WHERE "2015-03-01" BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) AND pattern.direction = "outbound"
GROUP BY journey.id
```

Above is two queries with their results merged by a UNION ALL clause. You will notice that the queries return different columns, one called 'departure' and one called 'arrival'. To get the `UNION` to work with the different column names I have to give the other column `NULL` so that it doesn't ignore it and not include it in the query.

My issue is I have results that looks like this:

`id | departure | arrival`
`1       asd        NULL`
`2       asd        NULL`
`3       asd        NULL`
`4       asd        NULL`
`5       NULL        efg`
`6       NULL        efg`
`7       NULL        efg`
`8       NULL        efg`

How can I merge the rows so that `asd` and `efg` match up based on the ID?

Desired result:

`id | departure | arrival`
`1       asd        efg`
`2       asd        efg`
`3       asd        efg`
`4       asd        efg`

Comment: Can you post the desired result?

Comment: @notulysses Updated question with visual desired result table

Comment: so you want the being join by? journey.id?? or randomly? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply an aggregate function (min/max) to your result set. As nulls are not included in the aggregate you will just get the combined results:

```
select id, min(departure), min(arrival)
from (your query) as q
group by id
```

Comment: I was struggling with the similar issue of union all with null values from one end. Thank you so much! I wasted a whole day looking into the issue and finally at the EOD I found this answer. I can always trust a human on SO over some random AI generated answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why did you try to build union.

Try this way:

```
SELECT journey.id, 
    TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l1.elapsed))), '%H:%i') AS departure, 
    TIME_FORMAT(ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(l2.elapsed))), '%H:%i') AS arrival
FROM journey
INNER JOIN pattern 
ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
INNER JOIN link l1 
ON l1.section = pattern.section 
    AND l1.stop = "370023139"
INNER JOIN link l2 
ON l2.section = pattern.section 
    AND l2.stop = "1000DEHS7812"
    AND l2.id <= l1.id
WHERE journey.service = "11-252-_-y08-1" 
    AND journey_day.day = 1 
    AND journey.code NOT IN (
        SELECT journey
        FROM journey_non_operation
        WHERE "2015-03-01" BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) 
    AND pattern.direction = "outbound"
GROUP BY journey.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your query will not return the same results.  Notice the second `link` INNER JOIN on both queries. This is required in order to calculate the value in the SELECT clause.

Comment: WHAT? the secod link was ignored in queries before. just try. I just updated the query with `l2.id <= l1.id` that you was highlighted?

Comment: I have tried your query, it doesn't return the desired results. Yes, it does merge them and remove the `NULL` problem, but you have missed the `INNER JOIN link l2 ON l2.section = pattern.section AND l2.id <= l1.id` for both queries.

Comment: that doesn't matter what I had remove from your query. what is count is what it return now? and what is difference from desired result?